# При наведении мышки картинка меняется

Tags: html, css

Уважаемые знатоки, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при наведении мышки одна картинка заменялась другой? Это должно быть гиперссылкой.
Я пробовал старым дедовским способом, которым обычно очень успешно пользовался:

onmouseover="this.src='рисунок при наведении'"
onmouseout="this.src='основной рисунок'"

Но сайт, на который я хочу добавить этот код, запрещает мне его использовать.
В то же время, около 6-7 месяцев назад мне мой друг показывал как это сделать на этом сайте при помощи CSS. Он выносил CSS-таблицу в отдельный файл и привязывал ее к < BODY >

Сайт запрещает редактирование блока < HEAD >. Изменения можно производить только в блоке < BODY >.

Я не знаю какой код надо написать в CSS, по какому принципу этот код будет работать, и я даже не знаю как привязать этот код к < BODY >, без доступа к < HEAD >.

Помогите пожалуйста. Если можно - поподробнее...
Заранее очень благодарен!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если правильно понял... я бы сделал както так:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .img {
      display:block;
      /*---- длина картинки ----*/
      width:100px;

      /*---- ширина ----*/
      height:100px;
      background:url(/img/someimg.jpg);
   }
   .img:hover {
      background:url(/img/someAnotherImg.jpg);
   }
</style>

<a class="img" href="http://someHref.html"></a>
```

Я думаю что дальше уже разберетесь...

Comment: Супер !!! Спасибо !!! Это то, что надо!!!
Очень Вам благодарен!!!

Comment: Приходьте ще %)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, строго говоря, HTML5 разрешает засунуть `<style>` в `<body>`, если у того есть атрибут `scoped`. Браузеры, впрочем, ведут себя по-разному, кто-то `<style>` в `<body>` принимает, кто-то, вроде бы, со времен когда оно еще было некорректным — нет. Нужно проверять, в общем — помню, что, вроде, кто-то из вендоров писал, как минимум, о желании отключить поддержку `<style>` в теле. Проверять что по факту — лень.

Вот как-то так получится вполне себе валидный HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <style type="text/css" media="all" scoped>
            a.image {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 100px; height: 100px;
                margin: 0; padding: 0;
                background: transparent url(normal.png);
            }
            a.image:hover { background: transparent url(hovered.png); }
        </style>
        <p><a href="#" class="image"></a></p>
    </section>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Пример вживую: http://pastehtml.com/view/b8cva3nu7.html.

Если же `<style>` не дает добавлять (фильтрует так же, как и JavaScript во всех проявлениях), то, в общем-то, никак. Можно придумать разные методы (скажем, хаки с `style="behavior: ..."` для старых IE), но это будут именно что грязные хаки. Проще купить хостинг и забыть об извращениях.

Comment: Упс. Пока писал — опередили.